# Advice required qa & testing

Tags: manual-testing, regression-testing

I have seen this question in forum before, still I am putting this, sorry for that.

I have work experience of 5yrs in manual testing mobile applications. Basically I'm searching a new job with a good company with defined processes and with good work culture. While searching the job I'm facing some difficulties.

My question is ,
shall I continue with manual testing or switch to a new environment so that I never face such difficulties in near future?

Please guide me, you valuable inputs will help me a lot.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you give us some more information about the difficulties you are facing?

Comment: difficulties such as not getting enough  intervies calsl from companies,some peoples says,there no demand in manual testing in IT industry..some peoples says..change u r environment such go to developing side or choose SAP like that..after 5 yrs of exp in testing its difficult to change my line..

Answer (score 4):

I am technically a manual tester and I just changed companies and literally had a slew of companies trying to recruit me. QA work in general is exploding as companies see how much value it offers them as a whole.

I have a feeling your issue falls into 2 categories.

1. A weak resume (Easily fixed)
2. Lots of experience with little to show for it

The question you have to ask yourself is how do you remedy this. A weak resume essentially means you are being screened out by the software screeners. Include the keywords for the position you want (use google adwords to find the keywords that recruiters are searching for, include it in your resume).

Also another good trick is to include your accomplishments. Saying "I am experienced with Test Planning" is one thing, saying "For the previous 3 years I have been organizing, developing, supervising and executing testing operations", which is likely closer to what you are doing, is better. And then provide examples of that experience.

As for accomplishments, you have to communicate what makes you a stellar employee and, probably more importantly, why you are 'just a manual tester'. I was asked this several times since I have extensive experience in nearly all aspects of the SDLC. The easiest answer, I am passionate about testing and love my job.

I hope this helps you out. Manual testing is still extremely important and needs more quality people in the field. A lot of people use manual testing as a stepping stone without realizing that the best manual testers can earn well over 100k while still enjoying their job.

Comment: thanks paul for u r valuable replay...pls give u r mail id..i wil share my cv..u can review it..

Comment: +1 for examples. I've been seeing hundreds of resumes listing same list of responsibilities over and over. I've been missing particular examples of achievements, like: "I've introduced hallway testing and improved percentage of usability bugs found" or "I've mentored three junior testers on system architecture and risk areas".

Answer (score 2):

Switching jobs often does not solve the problems you are running into, every company has issues on a certain level. Problems like a bad boss, undefined work processes and or a bad work culture exist everywhere and you will always get one or the other.

You get the work environment you deserve. The only one who can change it is you! Either accept the current situation or try to speak up and improve the environment.

In your current job it will probably be easier to standup and make the changes, in a new job you will need to earn credits again from the start. Also keep in mind that cultural changes can take multiple years before you see an actual effect, most people do not like change. Just keep repeating and don't give up, even when you think you are stuck for months. Try to see if you can implement a [continuous improvement process](http://searchmanufacturingerp.techtarget.com/definition/kaizen) to make improvements in baby steps.

Quality starts with the process, the process should facilitate quality end-to-end. Manual testing is just a small part of safe guarding quality.

Answer (score 0):

As other said, you should improve your resume, showing what you learned during 5 years of testing.

- Did your skill and responsibility increased?
- What exactly you accomplished, in measurable business terms?
- Or was it just 6 month experience repeated 12 times, with nothing learned?

Also, you can count yourself **extremely lucky** if new employer will take chances on you and pay you to learn new skills. It is unlikely. Better, learn new technologies **on your own time and dime**. Or try to sell your boss that if you learn technology X, you will be more productive. And then you better deliver :-)

I assume you are considering switching from manual to automated testing, am I right? You have few questions to consider:

- What of many technologies for automated testing is most appropriate in your current workplace? Selenium and Appium (google knows links) is popular option.
- What programming languages do you know? If none, **Python** is widely considered easiest for beginners (much easier than Java), and has Selenium bindings.
- But maybe in your special situation different solution is preferable. Your boss knows better. Or, you can do your own hobby projects in Selenium - it is free/open source.

Do not jump the ship before learning to swim. Learn new skills, **then** start looking for a new job.